# Angular,sails routing issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js, frontend

I've been trying to use angular routing in my sails app like this:

```
angular.module('SignupController',['ngRoute'])

.controller('SignupCtrl',function($scope,$http,$location){

        $scope.create = function(name,encryptedPassword){

            $http.post('/user/create/',{name:name,encryptedPassword:encryptedPassword}).success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            //$location.path("/user/new");
    });
};

}).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'views/tst.html', controller: 'SignupCtrl'});
      $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/homepage'});
}]);
```

so I'm expecting to get redirected on tst.html when I visit /view1 but I get a 404 instead. I'm new to angular so is there anything wrong in this code? I based my code on this example https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example

Comment: Make sure you visit `http://domain.com/#/view1` page. Note `#`.

Answer (score 1):

Angular routing works on the client side, so the "route" to view1 is not http://localhost:1337/view1, but instead http://localhost:1337/#/view1, otherwise you'll fall into the sailsjs routing mechanism, configured in config/routes.js (server side routing).

btw: I'd recommend you to use ui-router angular library, as it is more powerful and it's becoming the defacto standard for angular routing.